# Upload de imagens com crop e resize, com jQuery e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, upload, imagem

Preciso de uma função na qual a pessoa deve fazer o upload de uma imagem, sendo que ela deve "cortar a imagem", deixando no tamanho certo, estilo Facebook e depois deve ser salva no bando de dados. Testei vários plugins prontos, mas não consegui fazer do jeito que eu quero em nenhum deles.

Alguém conhece um plugin simples e que faça isso? E se possível um exemplo de código.

Darei mais detalhes: o plugin que deu mais certo dos que eu tentei foi esse:https://github.com/hongkhanh/cropbox, eu consigo cortar a imagem do jeito que eu quero, mas não consigo escrever novamente no input file para ser enviado para o PHP.

Pelo que eu entendi, o plugin converte o endereco da imagem que escolhi para uma base64 no formato `data:image/png;base64.....` para exibição na tela. Depois seria necessário eu alterar o valor do input para o endereço dessa nova imagem. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Será que existe uma outra solução?

Comment: Boa questão, útil e acredito que vai ajudar muita gente que tem o mesmo problema. +1 e fav para acompanhar

Comment: Upload por php com crop eu nunca fiz, mas já fiz com resize, caso não tiver movimentação eu publico uma resposta

Comment: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_3_material_design/form_image_crop.html

Comment: Não deveria está pendente. Eu poderia responder.

Comment: Olá Zoom, esse plugin parece ser muito bom, mas não consegui achar onde eu insiro a imagem via input file, que é o que eu preciso.

Comment: Estou pensando em responder a pergunta. Numa operação de crop, você precisa do plugin (que vai apenas gerar as coordenadas da imagem, ele não vai cortar nada dela "de verdade"). Daí, você manda essas informações para o php e processa com imagens do GD. Minha explicação seria um pouco complexa. Estás preparado?

Comment: @Lollipop pergunta reaberta

Comment: Olá Wallace, entendi o que você disse. Acredito que essa seja a melhor forma. Estou preparado :)

Comment: @RicardoAfonso ok. Já adicionada a resposta :D

Comment: Obrigado Wallace, vou dar uma lida e tentar entender. Depois posto se deu certo :D

Comment: Olá Wallace, tive um pouco de dificuldade aqui, mas consegui. Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vamos lá, vamos lá. Pode ser que a explicação seja longa.

## Pontos a esclarecer

Quando você utiliza um crop via Javascript/jQuery, você não está cortando a imagem propriamente dita. Você está apenas salvando as coordenadas, em relação a imagem que aplicou as configurações usando o plugin de crop, para poder fazer o crop com outra ferramenta. É ai que entra o PHP.

Entendi do que o javascript não faz crop? Então também está entendido que você não vai salvar a imagem cropada no input file para depois fazer o upload.

**Então o que vou fazer?**

Você na verdade vai fazer o upload da imagem original, enviando juntamente  com elas as coordenadas, através da submissão do formulário - vamos utilizar o método POST no exemplo.

## Como fazer o crop

O crop, como dito, é assim:

- O javascript capturando as coordendas, salvando em algum lugar (no caso os inputs hidden do formulário). Essas coordenadas são largura e altura do crop, e posição x e y do crop.
- O Formulário envia as informações para o PHP.
- O PHP pega as informações (as coordenadas do crop) e processa a imagem do upload, com essas informações, para poder criar a imagem cropada.

*Entendeu isso também? Então vamos para a próxima etapa

## O CROP

Enfim, chegamos aqui. É hora de botar a mão na massa. Vou passar as informações necessárias para criar o nosso crop:

**Requirimentos**
* Vamos usar a biblioteca `fengyuanchen/cropper`. todos os arquivos que vamos usar está nessa pasta do github [copper/dist](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/dist).

- O `cropper` acima depende do `jQuery`, no nosso caso de uso.
- Instalar a biblioteca php [Gregwar/Image](https://github.com/Gregwar/Image). Ela é excelente.
  Você pode instalá-la via composer ou então clonar o repositório. No nosso exemplo, eu vou usar o `composer`.

**Estrutura**

Montei a seguinte estrutura para o nosso teste.

`crop.php` - contém o código que vai realizar o crop da imagem.

`index.php` - contém o formulário php que enviará as informações para  `crop.php`. Também nele carregamos os javascripts utilizados no teste.

`default.js` - O arquivo javascript que inicializa o plugin na imagem selecionada pelo nosso input file presente em `index.php`.

`outros arquivos js` - Eles são os arquivos da pasta `cropper/dist` do github, além do jQuery, que vamos precisar. Então são eles: `cropper.js`, `cropper.css`, `jquery.js`.

**O código**

Esse é o código do index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Cropper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cropper.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="cropper.js"></script>
  <script src="default.js"></script>
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 960px;
    }
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Cropper with full crop box</h1>
    <div id="image-container">
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="crop.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y" />
        <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x" />
        <input type="hidden" name="w" id="w" />
        <input type="hidden" name="h" id="h" />
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image-file" />

        <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->

</body>
</html>
```

Esse é o código o `crop.php`, que é onde o `action` do formulário fará a submissão dos dados.

Depois que o upload é concluído com sucesso, eu exibo a imagem cropada. 
Nesse arquivo nós incluímos o autoload do composer, para poder usar a classe `Gregwar\Image\Image`.

```
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Gregwar\Image\Image;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $w = $_POST['w'];
    $h = $_POST['h'];

    $filename = sprintf('%s/croped/%s.jpg', __DIR__, uniqid());

    Image::open($tmp_name)
         ->crop($x, $y, $w, $h)
         ->save($filename, 'jpg');


    echo 'Imagem cropada com sucesso';

    printf('<img src="croped/%s" />', basename($filename));
}
```

Esse aqui é o arquivo responsável por inicializar e processar os dados do `cropper`. É o arquivo `default.js`.

```
$(function(){

    var $imageContainer = $('#image-container');

    $('#image-file').change(function () {

        var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

        var $image = $('<img/>');

        $image.attr({src: src}).load(function () {

            $imageContainer.html($image);       

            $image.cropper({
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              crop: function (e) {

                $('#x').val(e.x);
                $('#y').val(e.y);
                $('#w').val(e.width);
                $('#h').val(e.height);
              }
            });
        })
    });
});
```

## Explicação

**Uso de Cropper.js**
Começamos primeiramente pelo plugin `cropper`. Nós temos nele a função `crop`, que é responsável por retornar os dados (como posição e tamanho do crop) cada vez que o usuário "arrastar" ou "redimensionar" o crop, como coordenadas da imagem.

Eu tenho 4 inputs hidden na `index.php`. Esses inputs dei o nome de `x`, `y`, `w` e `h`.

Onde: `X` é a posição em relação a esquerda (o famoso `left` do css), e `Y`, a em relação a altura (a posição `top` da imagem).

`W` é a simplificação de `width`, que quer dizer largura. E `h` é `height`, que é a altura.

**O uso de Gregwar**

Essa é minha parte favorita, pois é o PHP orientado a objetos salvando minha vida.

Aqui nó chamamos a classe `Image` do namespace `Gregwar\Image`:

```
 use Gregwar\Image\Image;
```

O método `Image::open` é responsável por abrir a imagem. Nesse caso, eu preferi não salvar a imagem do upload e depois editá-la com o crop. Eu abri diretamente o arquivo temporário do upload feito.

```
Image::open($tmp_name)
```

O método `Image::crop` é responsável por cortar a imagem nas coordenadas que desejamos. Lembra que eu falei que o javascript só envia as coordenadas? Então é hora de pegarmos essas coordenadas, que estarão disponíveis na variável `$_POST`.

```
$y = $_POST['y'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$h = $_POST['h'];
```

Observe a ordem que os argumentos são passados, é importante não confundir, para o crop não sair errado.

```
  Image::open($tmp_name)
        ->crop($x, $y, $w, $h)
```

E por fim, salvamos a imagem. Com a função `uniqid` gero um nome aleatório. Escolhi que a extensão ia ser `jpg`. O diretório de salvamento é `croped`.

Então o nome gerado é esse:

```
$filename = sprintf('%s/croped/%s.jpg', __DIR__, uniqid());
```

A saída será algo parecido com isso:

```
c:\windows\php\crop\croped\24af43676.jpg
```

Então finalmente invocamos o método `save`. Nesse método, o primeiro argumento você tem que passar o nome do arquivo. O segundo é o formato que você vai salvar a imagem. Eu usei `jpg`.

O segundo argumento é muito útil. É uma forma de você enviar qualquer imagem via upload, mas todas serão convertidas para a extensão que você desejar.

```
   Image::open($tmp_name)
     ->crop($x, $y, $w, $h)
     ->save($filename, 'jpg');
```

## Github com o exemplo

Apenas faça o clone do seguinte repositório para realizar os testes:

https://github.com/wallacemaxters/exemplo-php-crop

**Nota**: Não precisa utilizar o composer, se clonar meu exemplo do github.

Faça bom proveito!

## Atualização

Fui alertado pelo usuário @Bacco para reformular a minha afirmação de que o javascript não faz o crop.

Na verdade, a maioria dos plugins, aos quais eu trabalhei para fazer um crop de imagens, o meio que eles utilizavam para fazer o crop era exatamente como dito anteriormente: Não era feito o crop, mas apenas enviada o upload da imagem juntamente com as coordenadas.

Porém, o @Bacco me lembrou que é possível fazer um crop de uma determinada imagem e mandar o corte feito para um `canvas`. Após isso, capturamos a imagem do canvas e mandamos para o servidor. Geralmente usa-se o base64 para efetuar essa operação.

O ponto importante de acrescentar esse último detalhe à resposta é que fazendo dessa forma (que o @Bacco falou) você pode diminuir o uso da banda do servidor, já que você não vai upar a imagem inteira para depois cortá-la pelo php. Você estará enviando o base64 da imagem já cortada, para, então, somente salvá-la.

Comment: PHPLegends é uma organização criada por mim e pelo @GuilhermeNascimento :)

Comment: perfeito, eu agradeço o tuto!

Comment: saberia informar o porque desse erro? Uncaught Error: Class 'Gregwar\Image\Image' not found in

Comment: Você instalou via as dependências via composer?

Comment: eu só copiei e colei o codigo via ftp